# how to get the android phone model, version, sdk details?

Tags: android

how to get the android phone model, version, sdk details?

Comment: follow SO strategy to get answer for your question....accept some answer

Answer (score 90, accepted):

First of all, have a look at these "Build" class at android-sdk  page: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.html.

```
// Device model
String PhoneModel = android.os.Build.MODEL;

// Android version
String AndroidVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.RELEASE;
```

Comment: Thanks for help . I tried it very long but could not find this answere .So thanks for help and i am granting +1 for great help

Comment: @Aditya1510 Thand and glad that my answer is helpful to you. :)

Answer (score 14):

```
 String s = "Debug-info:";
 s += "\n OS Version: " + System.getProperty("os.version") + "(" + android.os.Build.VERSION.INCREMENTAL + ")";
 s += "\n OS API Level: " + android.os.Build.VERSION.RELEASE + "(" + android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT + ")";
 s += "\n Device: " + android.os.Build.DEVICE;
 s += "\n Model (and Product): " + android.os.Build.MODEL + " (" + android.os.Build.PRODUCT + ")";
```

Example output:

```
 OS Version: 4.9.106-perf+(1909112330)
 OS API Level: 9(28)
 Device: OnePlus6
 Model (and Product): ONEPLUS A6000 (OnePlus6)
```

Comment: what is the difference between android.os.Build.VERSION.RELEASE and android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT?

Comment: @Exigente05 Release related to app version while SDK_INT relates to SDK version.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Build.MODEL](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.html#MODEL) and [Build.VERSION](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION.html)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend open library "Caffeine", 
This library contain get Device Name, or Model, have SD Card check, and many features.

this library is here.

https://github.com/ShakeJ/Android-Caffeine-library

And you use 'SystemUtil' example,

```
SystemUtil.modelName();
```